# save Exceptions to file in python

Tags: python, file, ubuntu, exception

I want to save all following Exceptions in a file. The reason why I need this is because the IDLE for python 3.1.1 in Ubuntu raises an Exception at calltipps, but close to fast, that it isn't readble. Also I need this for testing. The best, would be if I just call a function which saves all Exception to a file. Thank you! ;)

// edit:

*i had looked first for a more general way! so that you do not have to place your whole code in a function or indentation. but now that worked wery well for me. although I would be still grateful, if you find a way!*

thanks!

Comment: Why can't you run your script from the command line and look at the output there?

Comment: read it again! when I try to show calltipp with STRG + SPACE the ID(L)E breaks up. I want to know what type of exception has been raised.

Comment: Please answer my question.  Why aren't you running from the command line?  Why are you running from IDLE?  Why are you not running from the ordinary shell prompt?

Comment: Please also answer the following questions: Are you starting IDLE with a double-click of an icon?  Have you tried running IDLE from the command line to preserve IDLE's error log?

Comment: Oh, I just opened it with command line, pressed STRG+SPACE to usally get a calltip, and this helps. The error is now printed to the terminal:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/idle-python3.1", line 5, in <module>
    main()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.1/idlelib/PyShell.py", line 1420, in main
    root.mainloop()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.1/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1012, in mainloop

Seems to be an error in idle-python3.1 for ubuntu. Or what do you think?
    self.tk.mainloop(n)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode bytes in position 0-1: illegal encoding

Comment: @Joschua: Please update your question with the additional facts.  It's your question.  You "own" it.  Please expand it to include all the facts.  Please do not comment on a question you own.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If you have a convenient `main()` function (whatever it's called), then you can use the [logging module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html):

```
import logging

def main():
    raise Exception("Hey!")

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, filename='/tmp/myapp.log')

try:
    main()
except:
    logging.exception("Oops:")
```

`logging.exception` conveniently gets the current exception and puts the details in the log:

```
ERROR:root:Oops:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\foo\foo.py", line 9, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\foo\foo.py", line 4, in main
    raise Exception("Hey!")
Exception: Hey!
```